# Application of socket() from sys/socket.h

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a program in C++ to establish communication with a DLP Lightcrafter (Texas Instruments) without the provided GUI, and I've used these instructions to establish the connection:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream> /* cout */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket struct */
#include <arpa/inet.h> /* ip, etc */
#include <unistd.h> /* read() write() for socket */
#include <cstdint>
#include "PKT.h" /* calcChecksum() */

using namespace std;

/* Packet format
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * |                        HEADER                       |       DATA      | CHECKSUM |
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * | Byte 0 | Byte 1 | Byte 2 | Byte 3 | Byte 4 | Byte 5 | Byte 6...Byte N | Byte N+1 |
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * |Pkt type| CMD 1  | CMD 2  | Flags  | Payload length  |  Data payload   | Checksum |
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

int main ()
{
  enum Type{BUSY, ERROR, WRITE, WRITE_RESP, READ, READ_RESP};
  enum Flag{SINGLE, FIRST, MID, LAST};
  enum CurDispMode{STATIC,INTERNAL_PAT,HDMI,RESERVED,PATTERN_SEQ};
  enum CurTestPat{CHECKERBOARD_14X8,SOLID_BLACK,SOLID_WHITE,SOLID_GREEN,SOLID_BLUE,SOLID_RED,VERT_LINES_1W7B,HORIZ_LINES_1W7B,VERT_LINES_1W1B,HORIZ_LINES_1W1B,DIAG_LINES,VERT_GRAY_RAMPS,HORIZ_GRAY_RAMPS,CHECKERBOARD_4X4};
  enum PKT_Size{HEADER=6, MAX=0xFFFF, CHECK=1};

  char ip[] = "192.168.1.100";
  int *pkt=new int [HEADER+MAX+CHECK];
  unsigned int data_length, pkt_length;
  unsigned int cmd_CurDispMode=0x0101; 
  unsigned int cmd_CurTestPat=0x0103;

  /* Socket Structure */    
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
  sa.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
  sa.sin_port = htons(0x5555);
  int s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

  /* Attempt to Establish Connection */
  if (connect(s,(sockaddr*) &sa,sizeof(sa))!=-1){
    cout<<"Connected."<<endl;
    cout<<" "<<endl;

    usleep(1000000);

    /* #################################### */
    /* Request to Display SOLID BLUE SCREEN */
    /* #################################### */   
    data_length=1;

    if(data_length>MAX)
      return -1;

    /* First instruction - set test pattern mode */
    pkt[0]=WRITE;
    pkt[1]=(cmd_CurDispMode >> 8) & 0xFF;
    pkt[2]=(cmd_CurDispMode) & 0xFF;
    pkt[3]=SINGLE;
    pkt[4]=data_length & 0xFF;
    pkt[5]=(data_length >> 8) & 0xFF;
    pkt[6]=INTERNAL_PAT;
    pkt[HEADER+data_length]=calcChecksum(HEADER+data_length, pkt);

    pkt_length=HEADER+data_length+CHECK;

    if(send(s,(const void *)pkt,(size_t) pkt_length,0) != pkt_length){
      cout<<"PKT writing failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}
    cout<<pkt[0]<<" "<<pkt[1]<<" "<<pkt[2]<<" "<<pkt[3]<<" "<<pkt[4]<<" "<<pkt[5]<<" "<<pkt[6]<<" "<<pkt[7]<<endl;

    /* Retrieves answer from DLP */
    if(recv(s,(void *)pkt,(size_t)HEADER,0) != HEADER){
      cout<<"CMD reading failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}

    /* New Data Length */
    data_length = pkt[4] | pkt[5] << 8;

    /* Retrieves Data & CHECKSUM */
    if(recv(s,(void *)(pkt+HEADER),(size_t)(data_length+1),0) != data_length+1){
      cout<<"Payload reading failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}
    cout<<pkt[0]<<" "<<pkt[1]<<" "<<pkt[2]<<" "<<pkt[3]<<" "<<pkt[4]<<" "<<pkt[5]<<" "<<pkt[6]<<" "<<pkt[7]<<endl;

    /* CHECKSUM */
    if(pkt[data_length+HEADER] != calcChecksum(data_length+HEADER,pkt)){
      cout<<"Checksum Error"<<endl;
      return -1;}

    data_length=1;
    /* Second instruction - display pattern 0x05 */
    pkt[0]=WRITE;
    pkt[1]=(cmd_CurTestPat >> 8) & 0xFF;
    pkt[2]=(cmd_CurTestPat) & 0xFF;
    pkt[3]=SINGLE;
    pkt[4]=data_length & 0xFF;
    pkt[5]=(data_length >> 8) & 0xFF;
    pkt[6]=SOLID_BLUE;
    pkt[HEADER+data_length]=calcChecksum(HEADER+data_length, pkt);

    if(send(s,(const void  *)pkt,(size_t)pkt_length,0) != pkt_length){
      cout<<"PKT writing failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}

    /* Retrieves answer from DLP */
    if(recv(s,(void *)pkt,(size_t)HEADER,0) != HEADER){
      cout<<"CMD reading failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}

    /* New Data Length */
    data_length = pkt[4] | pkt[5] << 8;

    /* Retrieves Data */
    if(recv(s,(void *)(pkt+HEADER),(size_t)(data_length+1),0) != data_length+1){
      cout<<"Payload reading failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}
    cout<<pkt[HEADER]<<" "<<pkt[HEADER+1]<<endl;

    /* CHECKSUM */
    if(pkt[data_length+HEADER] != calcChecksum(data_length+HEADER,pkt)){
      cout<<"Checksum Error"<<endl;
      return -1;}

    if(pkt[0] != WRITE_RESP){
      cout<<"CMD Failed."<<endl;
      return -1;}

    if(pkt[3]==LAST)
      cout<<"CMD Success."<<endl;
    /* ############## */
    /* End of Request */
    /* ############## */

    usleep(9000000);

    if(!close(s))
      cout<<"Disconnected."<<endl;
  }

  else
    cout<<"Connection failed."<<endl;

  delete [] pkt;

  return 0;

}
```

When I try to connect to the board it's successful however when I send it commands I only get an error returned. I can't find mistakes in the way I'm sending the commands nor in the commands themselves, and since I'm don't really understand the way the socket works I thought maybe that's the issue...any thoughts?

Thanks

Edit:

I have edited the code to include an example of a set of instructions.
To communicate with the DLP vectors with 8bit components are sent.
First position defines what type of packet it is;
Second and third position are the MSB and LSB of the command to be given;
Fourth position is a flag that tells wether the data in the packet is complete or if it's to be compiled with data from other packets;
Fith and sixth positions are the LSB and MSB of the length of the data;
Seventh through Nth positions are for data;
(N+1)th is for the checksum `[(sum through the N elements)&0xFF]`.

I know that I'm getting an error because when I get the response from the DLP the packet type is 1 (Error), and the data is coherent with error codes available on the documentation.

EDIT 2:
Issue solved, the problem was related to the variable types and not the socket.

Comment: So, where is the code you're using to send commands? How do you know you're getting an error returned?  You left out some important details...

Comment: if your connection is successful it doesn't sound like a socket issue to me... but what error are you getting back? Is it a socket-related error or DLP error? If it's a DLP error you'll simply have to consult its documentation or TI to figure out what kind of comm protocol it's using. Perhaps the DLP is expecting data/commands in the reverse endianess from what you are sending? If you have the ability to wireshark a successful conversation with it (via the GUI) that would help immensely.

Comment: @FKEinternet, edited my original post, it now includes all the code for a command, explanation on packets and how I know I get an error.

Comment: @yano, I've used telnet on terminal and socket test to try to communicate with the DLP but I get forced disconnections when I send it anything. I've posted on the E2E forums on both issues, but got no solution so far.

Comment: @Joãomfras Excellent edit!  There's now something substantial to look at.  I'm quite busy right now, but I'll look as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Failure in a system call is denoted by it returning -1, not by it returning less than you expected. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, and there is nothing in the specification of the `recv()` method for TCP that entitles you to assume that a positive return value other than the specified length is an error.

Comment: @EJP, I don't think I fully understand what you mean. The error I get is from the DLP, it's an error packet.

Comment: @FKEinternet The issue was related with the variable types and not the socket, the DLP expected 8bits and the ints were 32bits. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: @EJP You're considering the test at the wrong layer of the protocol stack:  You are correct in that at the *TCP* layer, testing the number of bytes returned by `recv()` will not indicate an error.  However, at the *application* layer, if the number of bytes returned does not match what is expected, there was an error - which may have occurred in the sender, or anywhere in between.  Thus, the *application layer* test is perfectly valid in this case.

Comment: @Joãomfras I'm glad to hear you figured it out.  Variable types differences (bit size, signed vs. unsigned, etc.) are often some of the hardest to find, and may be the cause of more face palms when they *are* found than most other subtle "gotcha" errors...